# Linux Mint Volume not working as it should

Tags: linux, google-chrome, audio, linux-mint

So I installed my Linux mint but when I opened my google chrome and I was watching youtube it was too loud so tried to turn down the volume (f11 = Volume down and f12 = Volume up) but it didn't work so now I have to raise the volume manually for each app and I would like to know if there is any way that I can make f11 and f12 work normally.

Here is an image of where I use to change the volume manually:

Comment: Where is the image?

Have you tried using the Fn keys with F11 and F12 to see if that makes a difference? Perhaps the previous OS had it automatically selected to use volume controls, like Mac devices do.

Comment: @QuickishFM yes i tried! It appears in the screen the animation of the volume rising but it doesnt effect nothing!

Comment: ah, so the hot keys are captured. The problem resides in Linux Mint not passing the right command through to pulseaudio. I've never had this happen but have you tried a LIVE USB with a different version?

Comment: @QuickishFM I have Mint installed on my pc at this moment!

Comment: Yeah, so perhaps try a different Linux version (like an older Mint, or Ubuntu) through a live USB. At least then if it works on those, you can definitively narrow it down to your install, and then look for a fix that way. However, I'm petty convinced it's a problem with the install so you may want to reinstall pulse audio or similar packages to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: @QuickishFM I tried to uninstall pulse audio and installing and didn't work and tried to install pavucontrol but still didn't work. Is there any possibility that mint inst connecting my F11 and F12 to the sound control?

Comment: There is a possibility, though since Mint is displaying the right notification, it seems to be capturing it correctly but isn't passing it through to PulseAudio. There might be a package installed that Mint calls instead which is buggy, but you could manually delete the keyboard shortcut/binding and make your own one to test it out, like in https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-can-i-disable-popup-notification-for-volume-control/6968/4. This should change the volume without a notification - if it successfully changes volume, then we know Mint isn't communicating right with PA.

Comment: Also, please give information about the version of Linux Mint you are using, the DE (e.g. cinnamon, XFCE, KDE, etc), the version of PA, that can help us determine the issue. I'm running LM19 Xfce without any PA issues so it might be to do with your system only

Comment: @QuickishFM Iḿ using the last version of MINT

Comment: You should find the package installed that provides the notification, and check if there's a new version available. There may be a bug that is not sending the command to pulseaudio. Try to manually map the buttons to the specific command to change volume and see if it works - if it does, then Mint's included program might be at fault. You may wish to boot from a Live Mint USB that is a different DE - then check if volume changes correctly.

Comment: @QuickishFM So in that website that you gave me it only says how to change it to BackSpace but could you please tell me where can i find the f11 and f12 codes so i can set the way it tells there!

Comment: Is there no way to select the key you want? Where it normally asks to enter the key combination, just hit the volume keys as you would. This should capture it correctly. Alternatively if that doesn't work, you may wish to look into using `xbindkeys` which works very well. There are plenty of tutorials online for that if you end up needing to use it.

Comment: I tried editing the Keyborad Shortcuts and didnt work then i tried `xbindkeys` dint work! This is the config I made for xbindkeys: `# Decrease volume on pressing Super-minus
"pactl set-sink-volume 0 -1000"
   m:0x50 + c:20
   F11

# Decrease volume on pressing Super-minus
"pactl set-sink-volume 0 +1000"
   m:0x50 + c:20
   F12
`

Comment: Have you tried to capture the correct code for the key? You've duplicated the keycode and simply writing F11 and F12 wont suffice. You will get a unique m:0x and c:0x code for your F11 and F12 keys when you run `xbindkeys -k` from a terminal, and when the window pops up, press the key. That will give you the unique code, so try that in your xbindkeys rc file. Also, note that you most likely won't get a notification with this.

Comment: @QuickishFM Did what you told me but still dint work !